# Guava group by and order by members

Tags: guava

I want to group and order the elements by certain members in guava instead of sql.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM players GROUP BY club, country ORDER BY goals DESC";
```

When i try grouping by Multiset, it takes the entier class as a parameter and gives me back the list.

```
Multiset<Player> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
for (Player player: players) {
    multiset.add(player);
    //multiset.add(player, 1);
}
```

What is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use guava [tables](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table), for multiple key access.